# Backtrace a recursive program in c++

Tags: c++

Ive written a basic recursive code in c++ and cannot understand the working of it,especially line 13 of the code given below.Why is the value of c decreasing.

```
void count(int c)
{
    static int n = 1, g = 1;
    if (c == 5) {
        std::cout << g++ << "." << c << "is in if part"
                  << "\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << g++ << "." << c << "is in else part"
                  << "\n";
        n++;
        count(c + 1);
        std::cout << g++ << "." << c << "is after call"
                  << "\n"; //line 13
    }
}
```

output:

```
1.1is in else part
2.2is in else part
3.3is in else part
4.4is in else part
5.5is in if part
6.4is after call
7.3is after call
8.2is after call
9.1is after call
```

Comment: Calling a function recursively does more than just put the execution back to the start of it. Each call has it's *own* `c`. When you return from a function you resume the previous one with it's `c`, with the value *that* `c` had before calling the function that just returned. Each call to `count`'s `c` is unique to that function call.

Comment: try to replace the call `count(c+1);` with a call to `void foo(int c) { std::cout << "c in foo: " << c << "\n"; }` and see what happens, maybe this helps...

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting and while doing that I realized that this isnt the exact output from the code, maybe you want to fix that. Presenting output that doesnt match the code exactly doesnt make a good impression (beware of nitpickers ;)

Comment: user463035818 thanx a lot for reviewing my code but  thats exctlly the output that i am getting.Yes i had typed the output so is appeared two times,but i am not concerned about the message rather the value of c

Answer (score 2):

The statement printing the value of `c` is executed *after* the recursive call. So the complete "stack" of executions, each increasing the value of `c`, is built up before the value of `c` is printed the first time.

The first time `c` is printed when the stack begins to "shrink", starting with the greatest value of `c`, then going back to the execution one before the greatest value, and so on.